# Performance regarding the 'getting' of struct data

Tags: c++, c, performance

I have a question regarding the performance effects when taking into consideration of two possible methods of 'getting' data from a given struct. It is assumed that the 'name' variable is relative to what the value of 'id' is.

Assuming I have a struct and enum as follows,

```
enum GenericId { NONE, ONE, TWO };

struct GenericTypeDefinition {
    GenericId id;
    const char name[8];
    ...
};
```

Let's say I wanted to get the name of this struct. Quite easy, I could just refer to the instance of the GenericTypeDefinition struct and refer (or point) to the name member. Simple enough.

Now here is where my performance question becomes relevant. Say I need I create hundreds of these instances, all of which will be locked to a certain number of names and a unique id per. These instances will be referred to as a collection of possible 'GenericTypeDefinition's throughout the program. Keep in mind, the value of 'name' is relative to the value of 'id'. My question is, would I be able to save some memory if I implemented a function like follows (and removed the name variable from the struct),

```
struct GenericTypeDefinition { // 'name' is now removed.
    GenericId id;
    ...
};

const char* Definition_ToString(GenericEnum e) {
    switch (e) {
        case NONE: return "Nothing";
        case ZERO: return "Zero is not nothing.";
    ...
}
```

I assume it would because I am freeing up the need to store the string (8 bytes in length) in each struct that I create.

If you would like any clarification please ask, as I have not been able to find much on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you are putting redundant data into your struct. Essentially, you are able to get the name of the struct from the id in the struct. But, you could also store the name directly in the struct.

So, you are right -- not storing the name will save memory, because you won't store the name with every item. The cost is a bit of time. You will need to call a function to give you the name from the id each time you need it. You will have to weigh these tradeoffs to determine which is more important.

Answer (score 1):

The devil is in details. The answer depends on many things. For example, how often such a structure is allocated, how often it is used and how often `char name[8];` is used.

If you remove `name` from the structure, several scenario may happen:

- if you have many objects of this type and a good allocator, you will save space.
- if you use those objects extensively during some calculus and you use `name` only from time to time, you will save time thanks to better cache performance.
- if you use `name` extensively for some computation and your function `Definition_ToString` is just a little bit more complex than the one in your example, you will loose on performance.

However, in my estimation, optimizations like this can speed up program by some small factor only. It may help in cases when you count in microseconds. If your program is desperately slow, look for asymptotically better algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases compiler will do this job for you. It usually stores all the const string literals in the RO section of the executable.Depending on the optimization level it may even do away with the memory taken up by the char array in the struct. So your executable size will grow,but it won't effect the run time memory. 
However since the name is tied to the ID,logically it makes sense to implement the second version,so in future if you want to add a new id,you don't need to do any redundant work.

Answer (score 0):

In your first case, the task of initializing the structs with the proper ID and NAME means that the program will, at the very beginning, **copy** the literals, this is, the strings (because I assume you initialize the structs with the strings within the code) to another space in RAM memory, to which the *char[ ]* will point.

Instead, the second case means that the value is read from the program itself (the literals are hard coded in a table somewhere in the deep assembler code), and will return a pointer to it (correct me if the pointer is not to somewhere in the program but the returning const char* is stored as a variable), therefore you do save some memory.

My personal comment is (which you may see it beyond the question's scope), that even though the second alternative may save you some memory, implies that the IDs and NAMEs are **hard coded**, therefore leaving out any possibility of expansion during runtime (i.e. you want to add more IDs that are received via a console...).